# How does the sudoers option 'pam_session' correspond to PAM's 'session' type?

Tags: linux, logging, sudo, pam

On a CentOS 7 system, I want to prevent lines such as

```
May 20 08:55:05 c090 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 20 08:55:05 c090 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
May 20 08:55:06 c090 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
May 20 08:55:06 c090 sudo: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
```

from being written to `/var/log/secure`.  The `sudo` operations are coming associated with the user `zabbix`, so I changed the first line of `/etc/sudoers.d/zabbix` from

```
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty, !syslog
```

to

```
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty, !syslog, !pam_session
```

This prevents the unwanted logging and the appication Zabbix still seems to be functioning. However, the effect of the change is not clear to me.

Does `!pam_session` prevent the PAM `session` type from being executed, or does it stop PAM from being initiated at all?

Comment: I think this logs are coming due to this module pam_unix.so and there is no pam_session name module present in PAM.

Comment: The log messages say fairly clearly that they are produced by pam_unix.so.  The question is about the relationship between sudo's pam_session and PAM' session, in particular: Is PAM disabled for the sudoer if !pam_session is configured for the user?

Comment: I think you can check this article and use the same in your infra for zabbix : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/224370/how-to-stop-sudo-pam-messages-in-auth-log-for-a-specific-user

Comment: That's where I got the original idea from.  However, it still doesn't answer the question about the relationship between sudo's pam_session and PAM' session.